# Program freezing up, not accepting inputs? Correct clock?

Tags: c++, class, clock

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <ctime>

    using namespace std;
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
    /*struct*/ class Car
    {
    private:

    int carYear;
    string carMake;
    string carModel;
    int carSpeed;
    float carGallons;
    public:

    Car(int cY = 0, string cMa = "", string cMo = "", int cS = 0, float cG = 10)
    {
        carYear = cY;
        carMake = cMa;
        carModel = cMo;
        carSpeed = cS;
        carGallons = cG;
    }
    Car()
    {
        carMake = "Bugatti";
        carYear = 2020;
        carModel = "Chiron";
    }
    int getCarYear() { return carYear; }
    string getCarMake() { return carMake; }
    string getCarModel() { return carModel; }
    int getCarSpeed() { return carSpeed; }
    float getCarGallons() { return carGallons; }
    void setCarSpeed(int cS) { carSpeed = cS; }
    void setCarGallons(float cG) { carGallons = cG; }
    void accelerate()
    {
        startCar();
        if(carGallons>0)
        { 
        carSpeed += 5;
        carGallons -= .5;
        }
        else if (carGallons < 0)
        {
            carGallons = 0;
            cout << "Please refill tank!";
        }
    }
    void brake()
    {
        startCar();
        if(carSpeed>0&&carGallons>0)
        { 
        carSpeed -= 5;
        carGallons -= .2;
        }
        else if(carSpeed<0&&carGallons<0)
        {
            carSpeed = 0;

            cout << "Your car isn't moving!";
        }
    }
    void fillUP()
    {

        if (carSpeed > 0)
        {
            cout << "The car is still moving!";
        }
        else if(carSpeed==0)
        {
        if (carGallons > 22)
        {
            cout << "Car is full!";
            carGallons = 22;
        }
        else
        {

        carGallons += .2;
        }
        }
    }
    void startCar(bool carOn=true)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            std::chrono::system_clock::time_point then;
            auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            auto duration = now - then;
            then = now;
            if (false) return;
            {
            auto s = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(duration);
            carGallons -= s.count() * .05f;
        }
        }
    }
    };

    int main()
    {

     bool carOn = false;
    Car userCar(2020, "Bugatti", "Chiron");
    cout << "\nStart your new " << userCar.getCarYear()<<" "<< userCar.getCarMake() <<" "<< userCar.getCarModel()<<"!";
    cout << "\nHit O to start your Engine!";
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    if (ch== 'o'|| ch=='O') {
        bool carOn = true;
        cout << "\nCar is now on! Safe driving!\n";
    int c = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        c = 0;
        switch (c = _getch())
        {

        case 32:
            userCar.fillUP();
            break;
        case 72:
            cout << userCar.getCarSpeed() << " " << userCar.getCarGallons();
            userCar.accelerate();
            break;

        case 80:
            userCar.brake();
            break;

        case 75:cout << "\nleft"; break;
        case 77:cout << "\nright"; break;
        default:
            cout << " ";
        }
    }

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nCar is not on!";
    }
        return 0;
    }
```

I'm running into an issue where after taking input from the user to turn on their car the inputs freeze up and the switch doesn't accept any other inputs. I know it has something to do with how I'm calling my functions inside the switch but I'm at a loss for how to correct it. Also, I'm fairly certain I've incorrectly implemented my clock inside startCar, it's supposed to subtract gas while the car is on.

Comment: Unrelated: `carSpeed + 5;` should likely be `carSpeed += 5;` in order to perform the addition and update `carSpeed`. There are a few more similar to this.

Comment: Right, will correct that

Comment: Avoid using numbers where a character will do. The characters are more descriptive and portable. Eg: `case 32:` could be `case ' ':`

Comment: Discuss `if (false) return;` with [your rubber duck.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) Describe what you are doing here in detail. If duckie agrees that this is a good idea, then run your programmer in a debugger, step through `startCar`, and see if you're both right.

Comment: I ran this and it seems to work as I expected from reading the code. What do you mean by "freezes up". I can hit left and right arrows, things get printed.

Comment: What if I lack said rubber duck? So I changed it to true, everything prints.

Comment: @Garr Godfrey Well it's supposed to let the user use arrow keys to drive, it either only prints once and never again or doesn't accept anything.

Comment: But does the program behave correctly? The function will now always return half way through the `while` loop, making the loop pointless.

Comment: I mean everything except the startCar function seems to behave correctly. It's not subtracting gasoline each second.

Comment: That's because the `while` loop's not running anymore. When a function `return`s it stops everything dead and leaves the function. But if you leave the loop running, you have an infinite loop and the program can't do anything except subtract gasoline. You're in for a redesign of how you handle time and user input in your program.

Comment: Well what do you suggest? You seem to know what's wrong and I've been looking at tons of methods. What would help me understand how I can correctly implement time into my program?

Comment: Easiest I can come up with is add a `std::thread` to do the fuel consumption if the car is on and make `float carGallons;` into `std::atomic<float> carGallons;` to avoid synchronization problems.  Less easy is to go with non-blocking input and run the simulation in ticks. Gather the user's inputs and process them at the end of each tick. Make the ticks small enough and no one will ever know. Both are solutions rip-up your code quite a bit.

Comment: I tried std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));, but it's way too slow